Is God still creating new things in outer space or other dimensions?
Is God still creating new things in outer space or other dimensions?
Or did the Bible definitely state that He is done creating and that He is resting comfortably in Heaven admiring His Creation?

Is God still creating new things in outer space or other dimensions?
The short answer is no.
God's initial act of creation is finished and time is now running it’s course.
In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth: This tells us that God used no pre-existing material to create the earth. The ancient Hebrew word bara (created) is specific. It means to create out of nothing, showing that God created the world out of nothing, not out of Himself.
God’s act of creating the totality of the physical universe ”out of nothing" is now complete as stated in in the Book of Genesis.

Creatio ex nihilois the doctrine that all matter was created out of nothing by God in an initial or a beginning moment where the cosmos came into existence. It has been suggested that ex nihilo creation can also be found in creation stories from ancient Egypt (the Memphite Theology), the Rig Veda (X:129, also known as Nasadiya Sukta), and many animistic cultures in Africa, Asia, Oceania, and North America. The third-century founder of Neoplatonism, Plotinus, argued that the cosmos was distinct from God but was instead an emanation from God. This idea was rejected by Christian thinkers of the time on the basis of the creatio ex nihilo concept, and was also later rejected by Arabic and Hebrew philosophers.

God’s creation is complete is the sense that He no longer is in the act of creating new substances within the physical universe or invisible beings within the angelic universe. All is complete.

For by Him all things were created that are in heaven and that are on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or powers. All things were created through Him and for Him. - Colossians 1:16

All things have been created that will ever exist. Matter being thus all created within the universe cannot generate new substances, but may in fact be transformed into new substance though the basic laws of science.
For example, the substance of water is an inorganic compound with the chemical formula H2O. Bring two parts hydrogen together with one part oxygen and these two individual compounds make water: H2O.
New elements may one day be discovered, but they were all created at the beginning of creation.
The universe is continuously moving in space and transformations will continue to occur, but this is all a result of God put all things into motion. The universe is constantly changing, but within the rules that God has laid out from the beginning.
So as they say: There is nothing new under the sun, but natural changes will occur within the universe, as the course of time goes on.
Nothing in space is now being created by God. But nevertheless reactions in space are continuously happening such as nuclear fusion and nuclear fission.

Nuclear fusion is a reaction in which two or more atomic nuclei (for example, nuclei of hydrogen isotopes deuterium and tritium), combine to form one or more atomic nuclei and neutrons. The difference in mass between the reactants and products is manifested as either the release or absorption of energy. This difference in mass arises as a result of the difference in nuclear binding energy between the atomic nuclei before and after the fusion reaction. Nuclear fusion is the process that powers active or main-sequence stars and other high-magnitude stars, where large amounts of energy are released.


The sun is a great example that shows to us the universe although finished, is still in motion as God intended. The Sun is a main-sequence star, and thus releases its energy by nuclear fusion of hydrogen nuclei into helium. In its core, the Sun fuses about 600 billion kilograms of hydrogen each second.

Nuclear fission is a reaction in which the nucleus of an atom splits into two or more smaller nuclei. The fission process often produces gamma photons, and releases a very large amount of energy even by the energetic standards of radioactive decay.

The story of creation is complete, but until the last trumpet blast, the universe is still very much active.

We don't know about aliens, other space, other dimensions, parallel worlds, etc. (Did God have to send another Son to them!?) We do know that God is actively "indwelling" all of Creation otherwise it would cease.

Hebrews 1:3


The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of his being, sustaining all things by his powerful word. After he had provided purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty in heaven. (NIV)


who [The Son] being the brightness of His glory and the express image of His person, and upholding all things by the word of His power, when He had by Himself purged our sins, sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high (NKJV)


We also know that creation is not finished, there is the final judgement and the "new heaven" and the "new earth".

The Sabbath day is the seventh day, it is the day of rest in this world, the final day of the week. The next day, Sunday, is symbolic of the first day of creation, but also the last day of the Kingdom of God, the eighth day. The first day is also the eighth day, the day beyond the confines of this world, the day which stands for the life of the world to come, the day of the eternal rest of the Kingdom of God.
The number eight has symbolical significance in both Jewish and Christian spiritual tradition in that it signifies more than completion and fullness. Eight signifies the Kingdom of God and the life of the world to come, seven being the number of earthly time. (Orthodox Wiki)


...the Lord’s Day (Gr. Κυριακή), is symbolic of the first day of creation. It also symbolizes the last day of the Kingdom of God, the Eighth Day. In other words, the first day is also the eighth day. It is the day beyond the confines of this world, the day which stands for the life of the world to come, the day of the eternal rest of the Kingdom of God. (St. John the Evangelist Church)


In conclusion... try not to read the Bible like a textbook. It is a theological book, to help you towards salvation. It is not going to help you figure out things like science questions, because it is not supposed to. (Even the account of creation can be arranged like a cross andsets the tone of the whole book on the matter of Monotheism, our God created it all, no "lord" (aka Baal) no pantheon, etc.)
